# New Float order in endfloat

Tags: floats, pdftex, endfloat, newfloat

I have created new float(Map) in my document and I have used endfloat package but the problem is  "List of Maps" should show after "List of Figures" currently Map appearing after table Plese see the below code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}

\usepackage{float,endfloat}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\newfloat{map}{tbp}{lomap}
\floatname{map}{Map}
\DeclareDelayedFloat{map}{Maps}

\begin{document}
\title{Sample Title}
\date{}
\maketitle
\lipsum*[1] 
\begin{table}[h!]
  \begin{center}
    \caption{Your first table.}
    \label{tab:table1}
    \begin{tabular}{l|c|r} % <-- Alignments: 1st column left, 2nd middle and 3rd right, with vertical lines in between
      \textbf{Value 1} & \textbf{Value 2} & \textbf{Value 3}\\
      $\alpha$ & $\beta$ & $\gamma$ \\
      \hline
      1 & 1110.1 & a\\
      2 & 10.1 & b\\
      3 & 23.113231 & c\\
    \end{tabular}
  \end{center}
\end{table}
\lipsum*[2] 

\begin{figure}
\centering
\includegraphics{x}
\caption{A figure}
\end{figure}
\lipsum*[3] 
\begin{map}
\centering
\includegraphics{x}
\caption{A map}
\end{map}

\end{document}
```

When I use the following code List of Map disappeared

```
\DeclareDelayedFloat{map}[fff]{Maps}
```

> Current Output

[image]

> Expected Output

[image]

Comment: You might want to rephrase your question. Do you want the LoM right after the LoF and then the figures and maps? If I run your mwe I get LoF, figures, LoM, maps

Comment: @daleif currently Map appearing after table that is Figure Table Maps it should be Figure Map Table

Comment: I do not understand the use of `endfloat` together with the `h!` specifier. What is the desired result?

Comment: @Denis Current output
----------------
1)List of Figures 
2)List of Tables
3)List of Maps
       
It Should Be 

1)List of Figures 
2)List of Maps        
3)List of Tables

Comment: I have updated the question, Please see the image

Comment: @Shalu OK much clearer now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately I currently have no access to a TeX installation (and therefore can't try my solution out), but the following should work:

```
...
\usepackage{float}
\newfloat{map}{tbp}{lomap}
\floatname{map}{Map}

\usepackage[notables]{endfloat}
\DeclareDelayedFloat{map}{Maps}
\DeclareDelayedFloat{table}[ttt]{Tables}
...
```

The trick here is using the `notables` option which prevents `table` from being appended to the internal list of floating environments to be processed later on. This way you could add `map` before `table` to the list with `\DeclareDelayedFloat`.

Note: `notables` was introduced in v2.6 of the `endfloat` package. If an older version of `endfloat` is used (i.e. v2.5), the package option `figuresonly` should work fine here, too.

Comment: You can also use [nofigures,notables] and put them into any order you want.

Comment: BTW: Should be mentioned in the `endfloat` documentation. Will do so (and upload to CTAN) this week-end.

Comment: @AxelSommerfeldt there is no other way?

\if@tablesfirst
  \ifefloat@tables
    \DeclareDelayedFloat{table}[ttt]{Tables}
  \fi
  \ifefloat@figures
    \DeclareDelayedFloat{figure}[fff]{Figures}
  \fi
\else
  \ifefloat@figures
    \DeclareDelayedFloat{figure}[fff]{Figures}
    \DeclareDelayedFloat{chart}{Chart}
  \fi
  \ifefloat@tables
    \DeclareDelayedFloat{table}[ttt]{Tables}
  \fi
\fi

Comment: @Shalu Why do you want another way? It's difficult to offer a different way as long as I don't know what's wrong with this way. Furthermore it's unclear to me why do you post (modified) internal code of the `endfloat` package. BTW: Using internal code from packages in documents is usually a bad idea since this could change in future versions of the package.